# Classic asp - only receiving part of soap response

Tags: soap, asp-classic

I am trying to call a soap request from classic asp (it will be updated at some later point, but for now it stays classic asp), but I'm only getting half of the response?
When I use the request string in SoapUI, I get the response I'm looking for, but in asp I only receive part of the response??

---

### ASP Request:

```
Set oXmlHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

oXmlHTTP.Open "POST", "http://webservice-string?wsdl", False 
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" 
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "urn:action"


SOAPRequest = _
"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" &_
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:head=""http://header.com"" xmlns:ser=""http://service.com"" xmlns:add=""http://service.com/domain/address"">" &_
   "<soapenv:Header>" &_
      "<head:OnBehalfOfUserId>stine</head:OnBehalfOfUserId>" &_
      "<head:RequestId>?</head:RequestId>" &_
      "<head:AuthenticationHeader>" &_
         "<head:SessionID>?</head:SessionID>" &_
      "</head:AuthenticationHeader>" &_
   "</soapenv:Header>" &_
   "<soapenv:Body>" &_
      "<ser:searchVisitationRequest>" &_
         "<ser:UserId>Stine</ser:UserId>" &_
         "<ser:RequestId>?</ser:RequestId>" &_
         "<add:SomeId>1234</add:SomeId>" &_
      "</ser:searchVisitationRequest>" &_
   "</soapenv:Body>" &_
"</soapenv:Envelope>"


On Error Resume Next
oXmlHTTP.send SOAPRequest   


If Err.Number Then 
    Err.Clear 
Else 
    SOAPResponse = oXmlHTTP.responseXML.text
End If 
On Error Goto 0 

if len(SOAPResponse) > 0 then         
    Response.Write SOAPResponse 
end if
```

### ASP Response:

2018-06-25T09:56:36.016+02:00server_ID{bla bla}5

### SoapUI response

(made from same request - contains "**SearchVisitation**" which is the result I need!)

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <searchVisitationResponse xmlns="http://service.com">
         <ReplyInfo>
            <ReplyTimestamp>2018-06-25T08:47:48.204+02:00</ReplyTimestamp>
            <ServerId>server_ID</ServerId>
            <StatusMessage>{bla bla}</StatusMessage>
            <TransactionDuration>3</TransactionDuration>
         </ReplyInfo>
         <SearchVisitation>
            <OtherID>12345678</OtherID>
            <SearchVisitationID>
               <SubscriptionNo>Test1</SubscriptionNo> 
            </SearchVisitationID>
         </SearchVisitation>
      </searchVisitationResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you outputting `SOAPRequest` instead of `SOAPResponse`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo - it was a thing i tried out to see what i was sending, and i forgot to change it before copying into here. But the SOAPResponse is the one you see under "ASP Response"

Comment: Try `Set oXmlHTTP = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`.  It may not make any difference, but you're using the most recent version of MSXML - which often works better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried it, but I still get the same response

Comment: Maybe code in one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020211/sending-a-application-soapxml-soap-request-using-classic-asp) solves your problem?

Comment: I can't see what has been done differently in the link you sent? - except for the version of MSXML which is newer (I've changed that now, as suggested by @John)

Comment: Ok, I have played around a bit with SoapUI and some different requests, and it seems as if the strings that are sent in _some_ tags (e.g. `<SubscriptionNo>`) aren't received like they were sent? Can/does the webservice re-format strings? 
(btw other webservice calls work fine, only requests to this one is acting weird)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that

```
oXmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "urn:action"
```

was the part that would cause the request to error (I've - again - triple checked that the `urn:action` was correct).

Removing it gave me the correct response.